# Android accessible drag-and-drop

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, accessibility

I am working on trying to make an accessible Android application and we are implementing a specific kind of drag-and-drop UI widget (with a 'gripper') handle.

What is the best way to expose events in this kind of widget to an AccessibilityService like TalkBack?  I have been looking at [the documentation on Accessibility](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/accessibility.html) and [the documentation on drag-and-drop functionality](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html), and the best way I can think to deal with this is to assign an `AccessibilityDelegate` that adds the proper implementation, or custom firing of Accessiblity Actions.

Comment: I am not too sure you will get too far. The best source I know is on [Opera's dev network](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/accessible-drag-and-drop/).

Comment: Thank you Ryan; I am looking for something "native" Android-specific, however, and not related to HTML5 mobile development or such.

Comment: You can fire appropriate TYPE_ANNOUNCEMENT events, but there is currently no well-defined way to handle drag-and-drop for accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem with my app, [FPlay](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.com.carlosrafaelgn.fplay): I have a custom "slider" control, and I wanted to have TalkBack say its different values, as the user slides the handle.

My solution was to fake the event `AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED` as the value changed. Because of that, this solution works only in API 16+ (as it sufficed for me, I never tried to port it to a lower API).

The code:

```
public final class BgSeekBar extends View {

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED)
            event.setEventType(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED);
        return super.dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(event);
    }

    //When this method is called from within onTouchEvent(), fromUser is true
    private void setValue(int value, boolean fromUser, boolean usingKeys) {
        if (value < 0)
            value = 0;
        else if (value > max)
            value = max;
        if (this.value != value) {
            this.value = value;
            if (listener != null)
                listener.onValueChanged(this, value, fromUser, usingKeys);
            updateBar();
            if (fromUser)
                sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED);
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

*Noteworthy: this workaround is only possible because `AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED` is not used anywhere else in this class.